# SDL2: a problem with touch events (finger motion)

Tags: c++, 2d, sdl, game-development

So, I'm making a simple 2D game for mobile, and obviously it's controlled by touchscreen. However, I ran into a problem: when I move my fingers around the screen, SDL_FINGERMOTION event keeps registering for a while even after I put my finger up, and you're basically stuck for a couple of seconds unable to press anything. I have no idea what can cause this, and neither I have an idea how to fix it. Here's my code for a brief idea:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

using namespace std;

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1080;

const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1080;

int main()

{

    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("something", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    
    SDL_Renderer *ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    

    SDL_Texture *touchUpTex = IMG_LoadTexture(ren, "tU.png");

    SDL_Texture *touchDownTex = IMG_LoadTexture(ren, "tD.png");

    SDL_Texture *touchMotionTex = IMG_LoadTexture(ren, "tM.png");

    

    SDL_Event e;

    e.type = SDL_FINGERUP;

    

    SDL_Rect rect;

    rect.x = 0, rect.y = 0, rect.w = 1080, rect.h = 1080;

    

    

    

    

    

    while(true)

    {

        SDL_PollEvent(&e);

        

        if (e.type == SDL_FINGERUP)

            SDL_RenderCopy(ren, touchUpTex, NULL, &rect);

        else if (e.type == SDL_FINGERDOWN)

            SDL_RenderCopy(ren, touchDownTex, NULL, &rect);

        else if (e.type == SDL_FINGERMOTION)

            SDL_RenderCopy(ren, touchMotionTex, NULL, &rect);

            

        SDL_RenderPresent(ren);

    }

    

    return 0;

}
```

I tried to make an event called e2, so when the first ("e") event registers a finger motion, e2 gets registered instead. It got somewhat better, but I still had an awkward input lag for a split second when I moved my finger on accident.

Comment: Wrong event loop. You should have two nested loops: `while (true)` that does the rendering, and inside of it `while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))` that only saves the touch positions and doesn't render anything. This will allow you to process >1 event per screen update.

Comment: You probably should remove the double spacing of your code. It makes it harder to read.